# How to read input from the command line's standard input in Python?

Tags: python, stdin

I'd like to separate the input by an blank line, repeat reading the input until 2 blank lines are received. Here is the expected input format:

```
A
B
C

A B 2
A C 3
C B 4

A B 1
```

I have tried

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    node = [line]
    if line == ' ':
        cost = [line.split()]
        if line == ' ':
            distance = [line.split()]
```

But it can not stop reading input with 2 blank lines. Any advice?

Comment: line == ' ' - is line equal to single space character. Are use sure that this is what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple loop that stores whatever input you give in `lines`

when last 2 lines are empty i.e `lines[-1]==lines[-2]==""` then break;
[just mak sure that you have taken at least 2 inputs from the user so check `len(lines)>2`]

```
lines = []
while True:
    inp = input()
    lines.append(inp.strip())
    if len(lines)>2 and lines[-1]==lines[-2]=="":
        break
```

```
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

```
A
B
C

A B 2
A C 3
C B 4

A B 1
```

If you don't want to store all the lines

```
lines = ['temp', 'temp']
while True:
    inp = input()
    lines[-2], lines[-1] = lines[-1], inp.strip() # this changes the second last element by last one and the last one is updated to the new line that is entered
    if lines[-1]==lines[-2]=="":
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I store lines in separate list? I mean I'd like to have a list store everything until reach one blank line, then a second list store the following until reaching one blank line